# socket.id returning as undefined in array Node.js, Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to store socket.id's in an array, and randomly select a connected user to have data passed to them, although the socket.id's are returning as undefined, how can i store and retrieve the socket.id's? Here is my code:

```
var players = [];

// Socket Connection
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('A user has connected.', socket.id);

    players.push(socket.id);

    console.log(players);

});
```

Comment: thanks for the format

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create your own array of ids, `socket.io` already has one that is live, meaning it updates whenever clients join or leave. Use [`io.connected`](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-connected):

> The hash of `Socket` objects that are connected to this namespace, indexed by `id`.

You can get an array of just the ids using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
console.log(Object.keys(io.connected)); // array of ids
```

or an array of the sockets themselves using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
console.log(Object.values(io.connected)); // array of Socket objects
```

Comment: that gives me an error.  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Namespace.<anonymous>

Comment: What version of socket.io are you using? Also how is `io` initialized in your code? It's possible your `io` is not the same as the canonical `io` object they use in their documentation.